# Filter mongodb data via API requests

Tags: mongodb, express, next.js

I am trying to figure out how to filter data in mongodb Atlas via API requests.
My json structure:

```
{
_id: ObjectId,
level: number,
names: Array
}
```

I learned how to filter by `_id`. I pass the `id` via url, and fetch data with `filter` parameter using `$oid` in the body.

But the question is: how to filter data by `level` and get the list of data assign to certain `level`? I don't know what to use instead of `$oid` ‍♂️ If I just change the `id/_id` to `level` I don't receive anything.

```
const {
    query: { id },
    method,
  } = req

....

  const readData = await fetch(`${baseUrl}/find`, {
    ...fetchOptions,
    body: JSON.stringify({
    ...fetchBody,
    filter: { _id: { $oid: id } },
     }),
    })
```

Comment: Something seems incorrect - are you sure that the `_id` values for the documents in your collection are numbers and not `ObjectId`s? The fact that you are wrapping the query with `$oid` suggests they are ObjectIds (which is the default). So removing that wrapper and just doing `level: 123` (or some valid number present in the data) should work

Comment: Yes, it was ObjectId, thanks, I corrected it. You are actually right. You can submit it like an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference here has to do with data types. Your current query, which works when filtering on `_id` is:

```
{ _id: { $oid: id } }
```

The `$oid` component of this query is related to the fact that you are using the (default) ObjectId type for that field. `$oid` itself is the [extended JSON representation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/#mongodb-bsontype-ObjectId) of that data type. Other languages and interfaces have different ways of representing or constructing ObjectIds.

You have a different data type for your `level` field - a number. So attempting to do a similar query on that field such as:

```
{ level: { $oid: <value>} }
```

Will either result in the query failing (if the ObjectId is unable to be created from `<value>` due to its [specific structure](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/)) or in no documents being returned (since no documents have ObjectIds for this field).

Removing the wrapping `$oid` should solve the problem:

```
{ level: <value> }
```